# High precision sum with R involving binomial coefficients and logs

Tags: r, precision, logarithm, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to get the sum of terms obtained from the products of binomial coefficients (very large integers) and logarithms (small reals), each terms having alternating signs.

For example:

```
library(Rmpfr)
binom <- function(n,i) {factorial(n)/(factorial(n-i)*factorial(i))}

i <- 30
n <-60
Ui <- rep(0,i)
for (k in (0:(i-1))) {
    Ui[k+1] <-  (-1)^(i-1-k) * binom(i-1,k)/(n-k) * log(n-k)
}
U <- sum(mpfr(Ui, 1024))
```

returns `7.2395....e-10`, which is very far from the actual response returned by Mathematica, that is, `-5.11...e-20`.

How can I make the sum be accurate? I checked manually the Ui and all individually seem accurate to many digits.

**Edit**

Here is the *Mathematica* code that computes the same sum. It works on integers and only convert to reals once the sum is over. I increased the number of reported decimals.

[image: Mathematica code]

**Reason for this?**

In the end, I need to get the ratio of two numbers obtained with similar computations. When the two numbers are off a couple of order of magnitude, the ratio obtained is just simply unpredictable.

Comment: start by using the built-in `choose()` in place of your `binom()` expression and see if it helps.

Comment: @BenBolker: nop!

Comment: Yeah, I think this could be a challenge. (1) Are you 100% sure that there are no bugs/differences between what you have implemented here and what you asked for in Mathematica? (2) I tried a few things (ordering/grouping terms differently in the calculation) but without luck so far

Comment: Can you please show your Mathematica code?

Comment: @BenBolker I added the Mathematica code in the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to work with the `mpfr` objects during the whole calculation, rather than just at the summation:

```
library(Rmpfr)

i <- 30
n <- 60
k <- 0:(i - 1)

nk <- mpfr(n - k, 128)
(U <- sum((-1)^(i-1-k)*choose(i-1,k)/(nk)*log(nk)))
#> 1 'mpfr' number of precision  128   bits 
#> [1] -5.110333215290518581300810256453669394729e-20

nk <- mpfr(n - k, 256)
(U <- sum((-1)^(i-1-k)*choose(i-1,k)/(nk)*log(nk)))
#> 1 'mpfr' number of precision  256   bits 
#> [1] -5.110333215285320173235309727002720346864555872897902728222060861935229197560667e-20

nk <- mpfr(n - k, 512)
(U <- sum((-1)^(i-1-k)*choose(i-1,k)/(nk)*log(nk)))
#> 1 'mpfr' number of precision  512   bits 
#> [1] -5.1103332152853201732353097270027203468645558728979134452318939958128833820370490135678222208577277855238767473116630391351888405531035522832949562601913591e-20
```

Comment: Make sense! Many thanks at @jblood94.